# Can it be disproven that an electron is a wave packet of photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, antimatter

When an electron collides with a positron, both are destroyed and pure energy in the form of photons is released. It seems then that electrons are composed of photons, if photons were released on collision with the antimatter.
The process works in the other direction as well - gamma rays can collide to form positrons and electrons.

Other wave properties of the electron make it seem as though it must certainly be a wave, as it creates a diffraction pattern in the double-slit experiment even when 1 electron is fired at a time. Single electrons interfere with themselves.

The electron must be composed of something, if it can be transformed to photons. It must be a packet of some sort if it exhibits wave properties. Can it be disproven then that an electron is somehow a collection of photons?

Comment: Photons are chargeless.

Comment: Yes, it can: any packet of photons has an electric charge of zero.  With no charge, no matter how hard you try.  If really big "packets" split and acquire charge to get electrons and positrons, they are considered different particles.

Comment: What I myself would rather be interested in is if there is a difference between an electron and a tiny black hole that happens to have the electrical charge of just one electron charge, or what if it had two?

Comment: In the gamma ray matter creation scenario, where would you say the charge is coming from? Is it possible to determine why electric charge exists?

Comment: *The electron must be composed of something, if it can be transformed to photons.* No, that doesn’t follow. Particles can be *created* and *destroyed* in quantum field theory. Thus the entire premise of your question is false.

Comment: Can you explain more or point me in a direction for understanding how particles can be created and destroyed @Ghoster? I would like to understand more specifically how I am wrong; that's why I asked the question.

Comment: For overviews, you could start with Wikipedia’s articles on [quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory), [creation and annihilation operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators), [Fock space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space), [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory), and [Feynman diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram).

Comment: For the nitty gritty of how to calculate the probability of various processes involving elementary (i.e., non-composite) particles, such as an electron and a positron annihilating to two photons, see a QFT textbook like the one by [*Srednicki*](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf).

Comment: And of course this site has many questions and answers about quantum field theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, photons are neutral, so no collection of photons can have charge $-1$; moreover, they are spin 1, so no collection of photons can have spin $\frac 1 2$. Meanwhile equal numbers of electrons and positron have zero charge and integer spin.

If electrons were collections of photons, the anti particle would be an electron, since photons are there own antiparticle, but as we know it's a positron, but, if an electron were made of photons and positron was made from a charge conjugate state to that, then it seems:

$$ e^+e^-\rightarrow 2\gamma $$
$$ e^+e^-\rightarrow 3\gamma $$
$$ e^+e^-\rightarrow 4\gamma $$

...and so on...

would be hard to explain, esp. when QED explains the ratios perfectly.

Finally, the complaint that this reaction exists seems to imply photons can't be created...but that is how they couple to charge.

Comment: Thanks for the quantum explanation. That helps.

Comment: @PhysicistinEngineer'sBody so protocol is you upvote the answer, then I get my 15 points. idk why ppl want to close you question. Yes, if it were asked in a graduate QED class the professor would be all !?!, but this isn't graduate school.

Comment: I can't upvote yet unfortunately. I would if I could.

Answer (score 0):

In physics we prove things by testing them experimentally. You already seem to know what the experiments say. Our current (very accurate) model of quantum electrodynamic phenomena doesn't support your hypothesis, but there's no way to prove that some undiscovered model can't work as well and support your hypothesis. Do you have some novel experiment in mind here?

Comment: In my mind the experiments have already been done to release photons from electrons, destroying the electrons entirely - it seems reasonable to me that electrons definitely contain and maybe even consist of photons based on the experiment. However, I asked the question to see if there was any experimental way to deny my hypothesis. I do not have an experiment suggestion; I was hoping someone would answer with one to confirm or deny (although it's quantum mechanics and the answers are not always yes or no).

Comment: @PhysicistinEngineer'sBody *it seems reasonable to me that electrons definitely contain and maybe even consist of photons* What can seem reasonable is often completely wrong.